# How to sort a linked list by manipulating pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, bubble-sort

```
void NumberList::sortList(){
ListNode *nodePtr, *nextNode, *temp, *previousNode;
nodePtr = head;
nextNode = head->next;

while(nextNode->next) {
    if(nodePtr == head){
        head = nodePtr->next;
        nodePtr->next = head->next;
        head->next = nodePtr;
        previousNode = head;
    }
    else if(nodePtr->value > nextNode->value){
        head = nextNode;
        nextNode = head->next;
        head->next = nodePtr;
        previousNode = head;
    }
}
```

First, I am trying to get the while loop to iterate through all of the values.
Again I am trying to sort the list  by changing the pointers, not the values in the linked list.

Comment: this is exactly what you need: http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merge-sort-for-linked-list/

Comment: You haven't asked a question yet.

Comment: How to sort a linked list using bubble sort by changing the pointers and not the values

Comment: Implement a swap function that takes the nodes to be swapped (or an abstract reference to the nodes) to your linked list class. If the list is doubly linked, this is actually kind of easy. If singly linked, you have the added problem of finding the previous node.

Comment: I got that. The whole loop runs forever. What should I put in the whole loop ?

Comment: I was not clear. My apologies. First implement a method that performs the swap. Once you have `swap` done and tested, you can use any sorting algorithm you want. Sooner or later all of them call `swap`, and you just wrote `swap`. Do not build swap into sort; you just increase the surface area for bugs to hide in. Write one function that does one thing. Test it. Write one function that uses the first function to do one thing. Test it. Write another function...